# Where can I find information about the versions of Spring MVC supported by DXA 2.2

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2

I've looked in the DXA documentation to find something equivalent to the "Product pre-requisites" that we're familiar with from the Tridion product itself. So far I haven't been able to find anything.

What versions of Spring MVC are supported by DXA 2.2.1, and where can I find this information?

Comment: Hi @Dominic, you can start dxa-2.2 with Spring-Boot latest version

Comment: The nuance in the question isn't just what version of Spring MVC  is supported but where to find this information. I would expect answers to link to a [prerequisites page such as this one](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v12/GUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659) (it's not mentioned). If it's intentionally absent, then some context on why Spring MVC isn't or _shouldn't_ be mentioned in the documentation could be helpful.

Comment: Oh and if that's the page you were checking, @Dom, do consider leaving a comment or suggestion for our technical writers and team.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Spring MVC version in the (parent) POM of the DXA Web application.

```
<spring.version>4.3.24.RELEASE</spring.version>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the link of the Github:https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/tree/release/2.2/pom.xml

Yes, of course you may override this version (with any compatible version) in your application POM but I guess it won't be supported.

Comment: Thanks Shahid. I think the essense of my question was how can I find out what values I could put there that /would/ be supported.

Comment: @DominicCronin I realized that :-)

Comment: Interestingly, this file is not present in the `release/2.2` branch. I’m not a Java expert, but that seems to be an issue to me. May make sense to report an issue on GitHub for this.

Comment: @RickPannekoek I did find it here: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/tree/release/2.2
I've updated the link in the above answer.